# Modem gives public IP address instead of private one

Tags: networking, ip

We have a modem connected to the ADSL cable, then, connected to modem, there is a switch with 8 ports where we have 5 computers. The problem we face is that every computer gets a public IP address instead of a private one.

I'm trying to understanding what is the current configuration via traceroute, this is what I get:

```bsh
> traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  186-90-224-1.genericrev.cantv.net (186.90.224.1)  35.689 ms  35.976 ms  37.756 ms
2  172.26.14.33 (172.26.14.33)  37.752 ms  38.374 ms  39.114 ms
3  * * *
4  10.82.1.25 (10.82.1.25)  44.459 ms 10.82.1.117 (10.82.1.117)  45.920 ms 10.82.1.105 (10.82.1.105)  45.916 ms
5  10.82.1.5 (10.82.1.5)  47.047 ms 10.82.1.1 (10.82.1.1)  47.028 ms  47.715 ms
6  globenet-177.as52320.net (200.16.71.177)  77.661 ms  64.583 ms  64.605 ms
7  198.32.125.60 (198.32.125.60)  66.552 ms * *
8  1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com (1.1.1.1)  68.739 ms  69.096 ms  69.622 ms
```

The current IP address of the computer where this traceroute was made is `186.90.228.47` and when I search on the internet for my public IP address (sites like [whatismyipaddress.com](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)) I obtain the same: `186.90.228.47`.

Even I can't access to the default gateway (modem configuration interface) via its address (which is `186.90.224.1`). The only way I can access is connecting a single computer to the modem directly, then setting a static address to the computer of `192.168.X.X` with the default gateway `192.168.X.1`.

Can someone explain me what's going on with our network?

Comment: "We have a modem connected to the ADSL cable, then, connected to modem" A modem connected to a modem?

Comment: "(We have a modem connected to the ADSL cable); then, (connected to modem, there is a switch with 8 ports)" is how I parse it.

Comment: Nope, then, connected to the modem, we find the switch, it was a misspelling error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite normal. Your modem here is not acting as a router – it's not giving you any addresses at all, and it's not your "default gateway" either.

Instead it's acting as a plain bridge between Ethernet and EoATM *(literally what a modem is)* and so your computers are getting their DHCP leases directly from the ISP's router far away. That `186.90.224.1` belongs to the ISP's router, not your modem.

Perhaps your ISP expects you to supply your own router (or to manually enable routing features in your modem) if you want a private network.

**Many** ISPs work the same way (the ones which don't insist on PPPoE or PPPoA). The only difference is that most ISPs provide modems with routing and NAT enabled by default. (Of course, some of them also limit DHCP to one address per circuit to avoid abuse.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the modem doesn't do any routing. That's not necessarily wrong, modem's job is just two-way translation of one networking technology to another (in this case, ADSL and Ethernet).

By adding a switch, you can connect multiple computers to the same network the modem is connected to. They all get public IP addresses, because they are all connected directly to the Internet. In other words, there's no local network (LAN).

You need a router, which is a device that joins two networks. A router basically has two network sockets, one for each network to join.

So you need:

- a modem - to translate ADSL to Ethernet
- a router - to create a new local network and join it to the Internet
- a switch - to connect more than one device to your local network

If my definition of router sounds wrong to you, that's probably because until now you've only heard the word "router" applied to this kind of devices:

[image: A SOHO router of TP-Link brand]

These so-called "routers" are, in reality, a combo of two or three devices: a router, a switch and sometimes a modem. It sounds like this kind of device is what you need. So, basically, **buy an "ADSL router"** (which, actually, is an ADSL modem + router + switch).